# FATAL EXCEPTION: During Retrofit network request : Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting a Fatal exception while making an API call using co-routine and retrofit in android kotlin. And app crashes with below exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-7
Process: com.jamhub.barbeque, PID: 18525
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:656)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:664)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:131)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
```

Tried adding time out, CoroutineExceptionHandler

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                        val request = chain.request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .build()
                        return chain.proceed(request)
                    }
                }).callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()

                retrofitSocial = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build()
```

It shouldn't crash if the exception has occurred ideally it should return the request failure.

Comment: try to increase your `connectTimeout` to 30 or more.

Comment: I have to handle the exception to avoid the crash. So increasing the time may not help to avoid the crash.

Comment: What does your Retrofit call look like? Are you try-catching it?

Comment: @Egor I have it.  val api = InjectorUtils.retrofitInstance?.create(LoginAPI::class.java)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = api?.generateOTP(otpRequestBody)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {

                    when (response?.code()) {
                      
                    }
                } catch (e: HttpException) {
           
                }
            }
        }

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523119/exception-handling-of-network-errors-retrofit/58600120#58600120) might help

Comment: show us the code where you implement the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`

Comment: val api = InjectorUtils.retrofitSocialLoginInstance?.create(LoginAPI::class.java)
val job = SupervisorJob()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)
scope.launch {
val response = api?.generateOTP(otpRequestBody)
CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
Log.e(TAG, "CoroutineExceptionHandler", e)
}
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
try {                  }
} catch (e: HttpException) {
Log.d(TAG, "generateOTP HttpException")
ApiError.onAPIErrorOccured(e, apiErrorCallback)
}
}
}

Answer (score 6):

As per the error crashing the app - in your call logic you're try-catching the wrong thing :) It should be formed like this:

```
try {
    val response = api?.generateOTP(otpRequestBody)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { 
         when (response?.code()) { } } 
catch (e: IOException) { 
}  /* there are many exceptions thrown by Retrofit, all are subclasses of IOException */
```

Since it's not `response?.code()` that's throwing exception, but the `api?.generateOTP(otpRequestBody)`.

As for the timeout itself - you might have wrong URL, weak internet connection, you'll need to provide more info for us to find the reason out :)

Or you can try the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`:

```
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_ , throwable-> 
 throwable.printStackTrace()
}

//when you make request:

scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler ){

}
```

Comment: I am trying with weak internet connection and I need to handle the app Crash in that case and that is my requirement. Please let me know if possible. Thanks

Comment: Yes, catching the exception thrown by API Call or using an CoroutineExceptionHandler would be the way to go.

Comment: Exception is not getting cached, Getting the below error 

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
    Process: com.jamhub.barbeque, PID: 5462

Comment: hey guys can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/58799264/10800406