# Coroutines not running in sequence using async and await

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have three functions that I want to run in sequence using coroutines.

```
 private fun showAnimation() {
        busy = true
        mLog.i(TAG, "showing")
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            button.text = ""
            batchAnimation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            batchAnimation.playAnimation()
        }

    }

 private fun hideAnimations(b: Boolean) {
    busy = false
    mLog.i(TAG, "hiding : $b ")
    activity?.runOnUiThread {
        button.text = "give feedback"
        batchAnimation.visibility = View.GONE
        batchAnimation.cancelAnimation()
    }
}

 suspend fun getBatchData(): Boolean {
        var a = false
        // network call that makes the value true when the needed data is returned else a remains false
        return a
}
```

I am calling them as follows

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            showAnimation()
            val a = async { getBatchData() }
            hideAnimations(a.await())
        }
```

however the hideanimations function is called without waiting for the the value of the second function

edit: added getBatch function

```
 suspend fun getBatchData(): Boolean {
      var a  = false
        //  showAnimation()
        launch {
            context?.let {
                val dao = MDatabase(it).getUserDao()
                val trainerID = dao.getTrainerID()
                mLog.i(TAG, "trainer id $trainerID")
                json.put("trainer_id", trainerID)
                NetworkOps.post(
                    Urls.batchUrl,
                    json.toString(),
                    context,
                    view!!.feedback,
                    object : response {
                        override fun onrespose(string: String?) {
                            mLog.i(TAG, "response $string")
                            val batches = Gson().fromJson(string, DCBatches::class.java)
                            if (batches.success == "1") {
                                val batchlist = batches.batches
                                if (batchlist.isNotEmpty()) {
                                    mLog.i(TAG, "list length ${batchlist.size}")
                                   launch {
                                       context?.let { it ->
                                           val dao1 = MDatabase(it).getBatchDao()
                                           dao1.insertBatches(batchlist.toMutableList())
                                       }

                                    }
                                    mLog.i(TAG, "inserted")
                                    batchListSpinner.clear()
                                    batchListSpinner.addAll(batchlist)
                                    activity?.runOnUiThread {
                                        batchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                        //  hideAnimations()
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    showToast("Error no batches found")
                                    //  hideAnimations()
                                }
                               mLog.i(TAG,"setting true")
                                a = true
                            } else {
                                mLog.i(TAG, "error")
                                failedBatch()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onfailure() {
                            failedBatch()


                        }


                    }) { _, _, _ ->

                }

            }
        }
        mLog.i(TAG,"returning value")
        return a
    }
```

I added two log statements, one after setting `a` as true and one when the value is returned at the end. I can see that the boolean is immediately returned by the function without waiting for the api response. how do I fix this?? How do I send the boolean value from the callback

Comment: You don't need `async` to call suspendable functions, just write `hideAnimations(getBatchData())`. Unless your `getBatchData` is improperly implemented, but we can't see that.

Comment: I added the function, I just started kotlin so it is very messy. How do I fix it? @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: it's a `suspend fun` that launches concurrent coroutines, that's wrong. Do it without launching. Also you use an async call inside, you should instead make a `suspend fun` that makes the call inside `suspendCoroutine` and, in the response callback, resumes the coroutine: `continuation.resume(result)`. You are several steps from a correct solution, too broad for one question here.

Comment: ok thanks marko...I fixed it using a countdown latch for now

Comment: could you give such an example??